# Pig Latin to get output for SUM() function like this?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I have some data like (name, score)
A 10
B 25
C 15
A 5
A 36
B 98
C 78
C 78
B 12

```
data = LOAD 'demo.txt'  using PigStorage (',') as (name : chararray , score : int);
groupScore = GROUP data by score;
totalscore = FOREACH groupScore Generate data.name , SUM(data.score);
```

when I'm using SUM() function, the output is coming out like

```
{(A)(A)(A), (51)} 
{(B)(B)(B), (135)}
```

I'm wondering if there's is anyway I could show it like

```
{(A), (51)},
```

that is not repeating the "name" field for every occurrence?
Any guidance will help.

Comment: Your load statement is incorrect.... does it really works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is the query for the solution

```
data = LOAD 'demo.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (name:chararray,score:int);
groupScore = group data by name;
result= FOREACH groupScore GENERATE group,SUM(data.score);
```

Output

> (A,51) (B,135) (C,171)

Answer (score 0):

Group by name

```
data = LOAD 'demo.txt'  as PigStorage (',') using (name : chararray , score : int);
groupScore = GROUP data by name;
totalscore = FOREACH groupScore Generate data.name , SUM(data.score);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, still name field is repeating, I'm guessing it has to do something with FOREACH loop.